# Mac OS 10.9 doesn't display USB modem for Arduino

Tags: macos, arduino, arduino-ide

I am trying to select  `/dev/tty.usbmodem` on my `Arduino Lenardo` device. The OS is Mac OSX 10.9.

The problem is that it isn't displaying. I even tried installing [FTDI](http://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/VCP.htm) but it was no use.

Update:

```
sh-3.2# dmesg
luetoothUSBDFU::probe
IOBluetoothUSBDFU::probe ProductID - 0x821A FirmwareVersion - 0x0042
**** [IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport][start] -- completed -- result = TRUE -- 0xdc00 ****
**** [BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport][start] -- Completed -- 0xdc00 ****
[IOBluetoothHCIController][staticBluetoothHCIControllerTransportShowsUp] -- Received Bluetooth Controller register service notification -- 0xdc00 
[IOBluetoothHCIController::setConfigState] calling registerService
**** [IOBluetoothHCIController][protectedBluetoothHCIControllerTransportShowsUp] -- Connected to the transport successfully -- 0xe780 -- 0x3000 -- 0xdc00 ****

DSMOS has arrived
 mTail has not been written to hardware: mTail = 0x00000000, hardare tail register = 0x00000040
flow_divert_kctl_disconnect (0): disconnecting group 1
AirPort: Link Down on en1. Reason 8 (Disassociated because station leaving).
createVirtIf(): ifRole = 1
in func createVirtualInterface ifRole = 1
AirPort_Brcm4331_P2PInterface::init name <p2p0> role 1
AirPort_Brcm4331_P2PInterface::init() <p2p> role 1
Created virtif 0xffffff80174ed400 p2p0
en1: 802.11d country code set to 'TW'.
en1: Supported channels 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 56 60 64 100 104 108 112 116 120 124 128 132 136 140 149 153 157 161 165
hfs: mounted Recovery HD on device disk0s3
hfs: unmount initiated on Recovery HD on device disk0s3
MacAuthEvent en1   Auth result for: c8:3a:35:54:c7:b9  MAC AUTH succeeded
wlEvent: en1 en1 Link UP virtIf = 0
AirPort: Link Up on en1
en1: BSSID changed to c8:3a:35:54:c7:b9
AirPort: RSN handshake complete on en1
flow_divert_kctl_disconnect (0): disconnecting group 1
AppleKeyStore:Sending lock change 0
         0 [Level 5] [Facility messagetracer] [com.apple.message.domain com.apple.kernel.cs.mismatch] [com.apple.message.signature 1000] [com.apple.message.signature2 53a18aae61685cc356b171ce37cc504048ed45a1] [com.apple.message.signature3 b928c695e1e1a867d5fc392eb8f09e460f3139af] [com.apple.message.summarize YES] 
         0 [Level 5] [Facility messagetracer] [com.apple.message.domain com.apple.kernel.cs.invalidate] [com.apple.message.signature invalidate] [com.apple.message.signature4 343] [com.apple.message.signature3 GoogleSoftwareUp] [com.apple.message.summarize YES] 
CODE SIGNING: cs_invalid_page(0x1000): p=343[GoogleSoftwareUp] final status 0x0, allow (remove VALID)ing page
SMC::smcReadKeyAction ERROR: smcReadData8 failed for key B0PS (kSMCKeyNotFound)
SMC::smcReadKeyAction ERROR: smcReadData8 failed for key B0OS (kSMCKeyNotFound)
**** [IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport][SuspendDevice] -- Suspend -- suspendDeviceCallResult = 0x0000 (kIOReturnSuccess) -- 0xdc00 ****

**** [IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport][SuspendDevice] -- Resume -- suspendDeviceCallResult = 0x0000 (kIOReturnSuccess) -- 0xdc00 ****

**** [IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport][SuspendDevice] -- Suspend -- suspendDeviceCallResult = 0x0000 (kIOReturnSuccess) -- 0xdc00 ****

**** [IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport][SuspendDevice] -- Resume -- suspendDeviceCallResult = 0x0000 (kIOReturnSuccess) -- 0xdc00 ****

MacAuthEvent en1   Auth result for: c8:3a:35:54:c7:b9  MAC AUTH succeeded
wlEvent: en1 en1 Link UP virtIf = 0
AirPort: RSN handshake complete on en1
wl0: Roamed or switched channel, reason #8, bssid c8:3a:35:54:c7:b9
en1: BSSID changed to c8:3a:35:54:c7:b9
**** [IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport][SuspendDevice] -- Suspend -- suspendDeviceCallResult = 0x0000 (kIOReturnSuccess) -- 0xdc00 ****

         0 [Level 5] [Facility messagetracer] [com.apple.message.domain com.apple.kernel.cs.mismatch] [com.apple.message.signature 1000] [com.apple.message.signature2 3345639bd98273913ff25086fe0151f45fea0fa3] [com.apple.message.signature3 38872323d4adae2cb310de88ceeeae695630ffd7] [com.apple.message.summarize YES] 
         0 [Level 5] [Facility messagetracer] [com.apple.message.domain com.apple.kernel.cs.invalidate] [com.apple.message.signature invalidate] [com.apple.message.signature4 866] [com.apple.message.signature3 ksadmin] [com.apple.message.summarize YES] 
CODE SIGNING: cs_invalid_page(0x1000): p=866[ksadmin] final status 0x0, allow (remove VALID)ing page
         0 [Level 5] [Facility messagetracer] [com.apple.message.domain com.apple.kernel.cs.invalidate] [com.apple.message.signature invalidate] [com.apple.message.signature4 868] [com.apple.message.signature3 ksadmin] [com.apple.message.summarize YES] 
CODE SIGNING: cs_invalid_page(0x1000): p=868[ksadmin] final status 0x0, allow (remove VALID)ing page
         0 [Level 5] [Facility messagetracer] [com.apple.message.domain com.apple.kernel.cs.invalidate] [com.apple.message.signature invalidate] [com.apple.message.signature4 973] [com.apple.message.signature3 GoogleSoftwareUp] [com.apple.message.summarize YES] 
CODE SIGNING: cs_invalid_page(0x1000): p=973[GoogleSoftwareUp] final status 0x0, allow (remove VALID)ing page
         0 [Level 5] [Facility messagetracer] [com.apple.message.domain com.apple.kernel.cs.mismatch] [com.apple.message.signature 1000] [com.apple.message.signature2 53a18aae61685cc356b171ce37cc504048ed45a1] [com.apple.message.signature3 b928c695e1e1a867d5fc392eb8f09e460f3139af] [com.apple.message.summarize YES] 
         0 [Level 5] [Facility messagetracer] [com.apple.message.domain com.apple.kernel.cs.invalidate] [com.apple.message.signature invalidate] [com.apple.message.signature4 1215] [com.apple.message.signature3 GoogleSoftwareUp] [com.apple.message.summarize YES] 
CODE SIGNING: cs_invalid_page(0x1000): p=1215[GoogleSoftwareUp] final status 0x0, allow (remove VALID)ing page
         0 [Level 5] [Facility messagetracer] [com.apple.message.domain com.apple.kernel.cs.mismatch] [com.apple.message.signature 1000] [com.apple.message.signature2 53a18aae61685cc356b171ce37cc504048ed45a1] [com.apple.message.signature3 b928c695e1e1a867d5fc392eb8f09e460f3139af] [com.apple.message.summarize YES] 
         0 [Level 5] [Facility messagetracer] [com.apple.message.domain com.apple.kernel.cs.invalidate] [com.apple.message.signature invalidate] [com.apple.message.signature4 1549] [com.apple.message.signature3 GoogleSoftwareUp] [com.apple.message.summarize YES] 
CODE SIGNING: cs_invalid_page(0x1000): p=1549[GoogleSoftwareUp] final status 0x0, allow (remove VALID)ing page
         0 [Level 5] [Facility messagetracer] [com.apple.message.domain com.apple.kernel.cs.invalidate] [com.apple.message.signature invalidate] [com.apple.message.signature4 1781] [com.apple.message.signature3 GoogleSoftwareUp] [com.apple.message.summarize YES] 
CODE SIGNING: cs_invalid_page(0x1000): p=1781[GoogleSoftwareUp] final status 0x0, allow (remove VALID)ing page
         0 [Level 5] [Facility messagetracer] [com.apple.message.domain com.apple.kernel.cs.mismatch] [com.apple.message.signature 1000] [com.apple.message.signature2 53a18aae61685cc356b171ce37cc504048ed45a1] [com.apple.message.signature3 b928c695e1e1a867d5fc392eb8f09e460f3139af] [com.apple.message.summarize YES] 
         0 [Level 5] [Facility messagetracer] [com.apple.message.domain com.apple.kernel.cs.invalidate] [com.apple.message.signature invalidate] [com.apple.message.signature4 1988] [com.apple.message.signature3 GoogleSoftwareUp] [com.apple.message.summarize YES] 
CODE SIGNING: cs_invalid_page(0x1000): p=1988[GoogleSoftwareUp] final status 0x0, allow (remove VALID)ing page
         0 [Level 5] [Facility messagetracer] [com.apple.message.domain com.apple.kernel.cs.mismatch] [com.apple.message.signature 1000] [com.apple.message.signature2 53a18aae61685cc356b171ce37cc504048ed45a1] [com.apple.message.signature3 b928c695e1e1a867d5fc392eb8f09e460f3139af] [com.apple.message.summarize YES] 
         0 [Level 5] [Facility messagetracer] [com.apple.message.domain com.apple.kernel.cs.invalidate] [com.apple.message.signature invalidate] [com.apple.message.signature4 2209] [com.apple.message.signature3 GoogleSoftwareUp] [com.apple.message.summarize YES] 
CODE SIGNING: cs_invalid_page(0x1000): p=2209[GoogleSoftwareUp] final status 0x0, allow (remove VALID)ing page
USBF:    23925.735    The IOUSBFamily is having trouble enumerating a USB device that has been plugged in.  It will keep retrying.  (Port 2 of Hub at 0xfd100000)
USBF:    23928.637    The IOUSBFamily was not able to enumerate a device.
USBF:    23929.798    The IOUSBFamily is having trouble enumerating a USB device that has been plugged in.  It will keep retrying.  (Port 2 of Hub at 0xfd100000)
USBF:    23930.235    The IOUSBFamily was not able to enumerate a device.
USBF:    23931.688    The IOUSBFamily is having trouble enumerating a USB device that has been plugged in.  It will keep retrying.  (Port 2 of Hub at 0xfd100000)
USBF:    23934.686    The IOUSBFamily was not able to enumerate a device.
USBF:    23935.528    The IOUSBFamily is having trouble enumerating a USB device that has been plugged in.  It will keep retrying.  (Port 2 of Hub at 0xfd100000)
USBF:    23938.926    The IOUSBFamily was not able to enumerate a device.
USBF:    23939.752    The IOUSBFamily is having trouble enumerating a USB device that has been plugged in.  It will keep retrying.  (Port 2 of Hub at 0xfd100000)
USBF:    23940.583    The IOUSBFamily gave up enumerating a USB device after 10 retries.  (Port 2 of Hub at 0xfd100000)
USBF:    23940.583    The IOUSBFamily was not able to enumerate a device.
USBF:    23943.529    The IOUSBFamily is having trouble enumerating a USB device that has been plugged in.  It will keep retrying.  (Port 2 of Hub at 0xfd100000)
USBF:    23943.529    The IOUSBFamily was not able to enumerate a device.
         0 [Level 5] [Facility messagetracer] [com.apple.message.domain com.apple.kernel.cs.mismatch] [com.apple.message.signature 1000] [com.apple.message.signature2 53a18aae61685cc356b171ce37cc504048ed45a1] [com.apple.message.signature3 b928c695e1e1a867d5fc392eb8f09e460f3139af] [com.apple.message.summarize YES] 
         0 [Level 5] [Facility messagetracer] [com.apple.message.domain com.apple.kernel.cs.invalidate] [com.apple.message.signature invalidate] [com.apple.message.signature4 2478] [com.apple.message.signature3 GoogleSoftwareUp] [com.apple.message.summarize YES] 
CODE SIGNING: cs_invalid_page(0x1000): p=2478[GoogleSoftwareUp] final status 0x0, allow (remove VALID)ing page
MacAuthEvent en1   Auth result for: c8:3a:35:54:c7:b9  MAC AUTH succeeded
wlEvent: en1 en1 Link UP virtIf = 0
wl0: Roamed or switched channel, reason #8, bssid c8:3a:35:54:c7:b9
en1: BSSID changed to c8:3a:35:54:c7:b9
**** [IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport][SuspendDevice] -- Resume -- suspendDeviceCallResult = 0x0000 (kIOReturnSuccess) -- 0xdc00 ****

**** [IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport][SuspendDevice] -- Suspend -- suspendDeviceCallResult = 0x0000 (kIOReturnSuccess) -- 0xdc00 ****

MacAuthEvent en1   Auth result for: c8:3a:35:54:c7:b9  MAC AUTH succeeded
wlEvent: en1 en1 Link UP virtIf = 0
wl0: Roamed or switched channel, reason #8, bssid c8:3a:35:54:c7:b9
en1: BSSID changed to c8:3a:35:54:c7:b9
**** [IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport][SuspendDevice] -- Resume -- suspendDeviceCallResult = 0x0000 (kIOReturnSuccess) -- 0xdc00 ****

**** [IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport][SuspendDevice] -- Suspend -- suspendDeviceCallResult = 0x0000 (kIOReturnSuccess) -- 0xdc00 ****

wlEvent: en1 en1 Link DOWN virtIf = 0
AirPort: Link Down on en1. Reason 8 (Disassociated because station leaving).
**** [IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport][SuspendDevice] -- Resume -- suspendDeviceCallResult = 0x0000 (kIOReturnSuccess) -- 0xdc00 ****

flow_divert_kctl_disconnect (0): disconnecting group 1
flow_divert_kctl_disconnect (0): disconnecting group 1
MacAuthEvent en1   Auth result for: c8:3a:35:54:c7:b9  MAC AUTH succeeded
wlEvent: en1 en1 Link UP virtIf = 0
AirPort: Link Up on en1
en1: BSSID changed to c8:3a:35:54:c7:b9
wlEvent: en1 en1 Link DOWN virtIf = 0
AirPort: Link Down on en1. Reason 8 (Disassociated because station leaving).
MacAuthEvent en1   Auth result for: c8:3a:35:54:c7:b9  MAC AUTH succeeded
wlEvent: en1 en1 Link UP virtIf = 0
AirPort: Link Up on en1
en1: BSSID changed to c8:3a:35:54:c7:b9
wlEvent: en1 en1 Link DOWN virtIf = 0
AirPort: Link Down on en1. Reason 8 (Disassociated because station leaving).
MacAuthEvent en1   Auth result for: c8:3a:35:54:c7:b9  MAC AUTH succeeded
wlEvent: en1 en1 Link UP virtIf = 0
AirPort: Link Up on en1
en1: BSSID changed to c8:3a:35:54:c7:b9
wlEvent: en1 en1 Link DOWN virtIf = 0
AirPort: Link Down on en1. Reason 8 (Disassociated because station leaving).
en1: 802.11d country code set to 'X2'.
en1: Supported channels 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 36 40 44 48 52 56 60 64 100 104 108 112 116 120 124 128 132 136 140 149 153 157 161 165
en1: 802.11d country code set to 'TW'.
en1: Supported channels 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 56 60 64 100 104 108 112 116 120 124 128 132 136 140 149 153 157 161 165
**** [IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport][SuspendDevice] -- Suspend -- suspendDeviceCallResult = 0x0000 (kIOReturnSuccess) -- 0xdc00 ****

MacAuthEvent en1   Auth result for: c8:3a:35:54:c7:b9  MAC AUTH succeeded
wlEvent: en1 en1 Link UP virtIf = 0
AirPort: Link Up on en1
en1: BSSID changed to c8:3a:35:54:c7:b9
AirPort: RSN handshake complete on en1
**** [IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport][SuspendDevice] -- Resume -- suspendDeviceCallResult = 0x0000 (kIOReturnSuccess) -- 0xdc00 ****

flow_divert_kctl_disconnect (0): disconnecting group 1
**** [IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport][SuspendDevice] -- Suspend -- suspendDeviceCallResult = 0x0000 (kIOReturnSuccess) -- 0xdc00 ****

ttyioss12000000: enqueueData rtn (e00002d8)
ttyioss12000000: enqueueData rtn (e00002d8)
USBF:    25854.340    The IOUSBFamily is having trouble enumerating a USB device that has been plugged in.  It will keep retrying.  (Port 2 of Hub at 0xfd100000)
USBF:    25857.339    The IOUSBFamily was not able to enumerate a device.
USBF:    25858.179    The IOUSBFamily is having trouble enumerating a USB device that has been plugged in.  It will keep retrying.  (Port 2 of Hub at 0xfd100000)
USBF:    25861.579    The IOUSBFamily was not able to enumerate a device.
ttyioss12000000: enqueueData rtn (e00002d8)
ttyioss12000000: enqueueData rtn (e00002d8)
USBF:    25862.402    The IOUSBFamily is having trouble enumerating a USB device that has been plugged in.  It will keep retrying.  (Port 2 of Hub at 0xfd100000)
USBF:    25863.237    The IOUSBFamily gave up enumerating a USB device after 10 retries.  (Port 2 of Hub at 0xfd100000)
USBF:    25863.237    The IOUSBFamily was not able to enumerate a device.
ttyioss12000000: enqueueData rtn (e00002d8)
ttyioss12000000: enqueueData rtn (e00002d8)
USBF:    26089.162    The IOUSBFamily is having trouble enumerating a USB device that has been plugged in.  It will keep retrying.  (Port 2 of Hub at 0xfd100000)
USBF:    26089.593    The IOUSBFamily was not able to enumerate a device.
USBF:    26090.343    The IOUSBFamily is having trouble enumerating a USB device that has been plugged in.  It will keep retrying.  (Port 2 of Hub at 0xfd100000)
USBF:    26090.344    The IOUSBFamily was not able to enumerate a device.
USBF:    26092.428    The IOUSBFamily is having trouble enumerating a USB device that has been plugged in.  It will keep retrying.  (Port 2 of Hub at 0xfd100000)
USBF:    26100.388    The IOUSBFamily was not able to enumerate a device.
USBF:    26101.231    The IOUSBFamily is having trouble enumerating a USB device that has been plugged in.  It will keep retrying.  (Port 2 of Hub at 0xfd100000)
USBF:    26101.965    The IOUSBFamily was not able to enumerate a device.
USBF:    26124.500    The IOUSBFamily is having trouble enumerating a USB device that has been plugged in.  It will keep retrying.  (Port 2 of Hub at 0xfd100000)
USBF:    26127.496    The IOUSBFamily was not able to enumerate a device.
USBF:    26128.340    The IOUSBFamily is having trouble enumerating a USB device that has been plugged in.  It will keep retrying.  (Port 2 of Hub at 0xfd100000)
USBF:    26131.738    The IOUSBFamily was not able to enumerate a device.
USBF:    26132.565    The IOUSBFamily is having trouble enumerating a USB device that has been plugged in.  It will keep retrying.  (Port 2 of Hub at 0xfd100000)
USBF:    26133.396    The IOUSBFamily gave up enumerating a USB device after 10 retries.  (Port 2 of Hub at 0xfd100000)
USBF:    26133.396    The IOUSBFamily was not able to enumerate a device.
sh-3.2#
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disconnect your Arduino from your Mac. Open the Applications folder on Mac, start "Terminal". Now, in the Terminal window, type "dmesg". This will show you the console log.

Now, plug in your Arduino, and re-run the dmesg command. You should see a message if OS" has detected the Leonardo, and also the OSX device created for it. (eg /dev/ttyUSB0) If not, you may have a hardware problem with the device, or cable...

Comment: I have updated my post. I have added the output after typing `dmesg` (The output was obtained after attaching the arduino). Any clue what's wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure, to be honest. Clearly OSX is complaining about a problem with the USB device, which I am guessing is the Arduino. Is there any chance you can try another cable, or another arduino? Or failing that, connect the arduino to a windows machine, and see if you get a new COM port? It could be hardware or software. The Leonardo implements a USB CDC Profile in software... (Doesn't use the FTDI chipset.) Have you programmed the Leonardo? Is there any chance you've caused a big delay in the software loop() method? The sketches need to loop and handle USB events....

Comment: The most common cause of this failure is a power only USB. Can't count the number of times I've had to relearn this lesson. But I discovered something new over the last three days when a previous working Mega 2560 was no longer visible. I was running a strip of 50 or so LEDs off the power pin. When I unplugged these, the port appeared. So check if you've got peripherals drawing too much power from the board.